# What is the space character in Perl?

Tags: perl, space

I want to have this output

```
"type":"test test"
```

I don't want to use space in the command not like " ".
I want to have a character that represents a single space, and I know that I can not use **\s**.

Is there some thing I can use?

```
print "\"type\":\"test(space character should be here )test\";
```

Comment: Why not use `print q{type":"test test"};` What purpose does not using `' '` serve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution really is to use the space key directly:

```
print q("type":"test test"); # Changed delimiter for fewer escapes
```

But if you want to, you can also use

- `\x20`, the ASCII code for “Space”, or
- `\N{SPACE}`, the Unicode charname for the normal space (there are many more).
- `\N{U+0020}`, the Unicode codepoint for the normal space.
- …

Note that these only work in double-quoted strings, e.g. `qq(...)`.

If you want to go the charname route, then you have to load the `charnames` module prior to Perl 5.16:

```
 use charnames ':full';
```

Since 5.16, that module is loaded automatically once an `\N{...}` escape is found.

By default, the `$"` variable contains a single space – the contents of this variable are used to concatenate the contents of an array when it is interpolated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the space key:

```
print "\"type\":\"test test\"";
#                     ^
```